# Array with char and integer

Tags: c, arrays

I just started learning array in C language. 
1. Tryed to print out item names and prices, but getting error, While compiling no error gives, but when i run it gives error. 
 What did i do wrong here ?

Here is my code

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    int main(void){

        float p[7]={0.55,0.8,1,1.2,0.95,0.4,0.6};
        int i=1;

        printf("%s%10s\n","#Item","ItemName");
            for(i=1;i<8;i++){

                printf("%s%13f0.2\n",i,p[i]);
    }

        return 0;

    }
```

2.How i can list names? i tried with `char` but didnt worked well.

```
char n[10]={'Water','Cola','Fanta','Chokolate','Biscuit','Gum','Candy'};
```

this gives errl4    14  C:\Users\Erdene\Desktop\turshilt.c

```
[Warning] character constant too long for its type
```

if i change n[100] how can i list with Numbering and pricing?

like listing numbers and next to numbers Item and prices.
 any advices? thanks

Comment: Arrays in C are indexed starting at `0` not at `1`. So you're array index is out of bounds when it hits the value `7`. It should go from `0` to `6`.

Comment: enable all warnings, and you'll see something about multibyte character constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float p[7]={0.55,0.8,1,1.2,0.95,0.4,0.6};
```

Arrays in C are indexed starting with 0, so your `for` loop should be

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) { ... }
```

For the other part of your question:

```
char n[10]={'Water','Cola','Fanta','Chokolate','Biscuit','Gum','Candy'};
```

you should use double quotes for the strings (single quotes are for character
constants).   `n` should be an array of ten *pointers*, not ten *characters*,
and it's good practice to make the array size the same as the number of initializers:

```
char *n[7]={"Water","Cola","Fanta","Chokolate","Biscuit","Gum","Candy"};
```

Comment: I just realize that `printf("%s%13f0.2\n",i,p[i]);` part is wrong, `printf("%s%13 0.2f\n",i,p[i]);` is also wrong. How i can use that 13 and 0.2 together ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that there is a difference between an array of `char` type values, which is what you have, and an array of strings.

You denote a single char value using a number, or single quotes like so

```
char bar = 65;
char foo = 'A';
```

Both of these are the same value. `char` can only store one character of information, the size is restricted by a byte.

When you're declaring a string of `char`s use double quotes

```
char string[100] = "Hello!";
```

As an alternative to what Jim Lewis has posted, you can use a constant size array, if you know that at compile time. In this instance, you are required to specify all but the outer-most level size.

```
// This will store as many 19 letter words, as you specify in the declaration
char strings[][20] = {"One", "word", "two", "words"};
// The index starts at zero
printf("%s\n", strings[0]); // -> One
printf("%s\n", strings[1]); // -> word
printf("%s\n", strings[2]); // -> two
printf("%s\n", strings[3]); // -> words
printf("%s\n", strings[4]); // -> ERROR - out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the other answers to explain why.  Read the example below for a full example of how to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    // array sizes do not need to be explicitly set when initialized this way
    char *n[]={"Water","Cola","Fanta","Chokolate","Biscuit","Gum","Candy"};
    float p[]={0.55,0.8,1,1.2,0.95,0.4,0.6};
    int i;
    // calculate array length, so can change array length without breaking code
    int len = sizeof(n)/sizeof(*n);

    // tinker with printf if you want to make the columns wider, etc.
    printf("%s%11s%9s\n", "Item #", "Item Name", "Price");
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%6d  %-10s%8.2f\n", i + 1, n[i], p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yea its working well, but how that `printf("%6d  %-10s%8.2f\n", i + 1, n[i], p[i]);` printing perfect ? `%-10s` means to lefthand side 10 Isnt it ? but `n[i]` shows right under the `ItemName` how?

Comment: Header has %s%11s for "Item #" and "Item Name".  "Item #" is printed as-is, 6 characters.  "Item Name", whose length is 9, is printed right-justified in 11 spaces, providing 2 blank spaces before the text.  As a result, the text "Item Name" starts in column 9.  The detail line has "%6d  %-10s", so likewise, n[i] is printed starting in column 9.  The header could be rewritten as "%6s  %9s    %5s" to make it easier to see how they line up.